# Connecting the names

Tags: connections-puzzle

What relation do these five names share.

- Henry
- Eddie
- Murray
- Vic
- Roy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The five names are:

> Metal Mascots

Henry

> Henry is a bit murky but he was certainly being used to promote the band in 1978. As far as mascots go, Henry showed up fairly late in the Sabbath saga. (Fallen Angel)

Eddie

> Iron Maiden’s famous mascot was simply known as Ed the Head. He is the single-most recognizable figure in all of heavy metal.

Murray

> An evil creature with blood red eyes, our first glimpse of Murray shows this beast choking a drowning priest with iron chains. Murray first appeared on the seminal heavy metal release, ‘Holy Diver.’ Dio

Vic

> Vic Rattlehead was the skeletal representative of Megadeth right from the start. Megadeth’s Vic Rattlehead is one of the most beloved mascots in heavy metal.

Roy

> Roy is quite the appropriate mascot to represent the hyper-melodic extreme metal band that has taken the guitar world by storm.
> Children of Bodom